# Issue with AJAX, JSON and PHP return value

Tags: php, ajax, json

I'm trying to write a script that pass geolocation's lat and lng as an array to PHP and return a value to the client side by using jQuery AJAX. The best solution that i could find was JSON. My following scripts return me `NULL` value for some reason that i couldn't tell.

**index.html**

```
<div id="geoloc"></div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
            if(navigator.geolocation){
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
            } else {
                $('#geoloc').html("<p>Geolocation is not supported by this browser</p>");
            }

            function showPosition(position) {
                var latlng = [ {"lat":position.coords.latitude, "lng":position.coords.longitude}];

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "libs/filterstores.php",
                    data: { json: JSON.stringify(latlng) },
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#geoloc').html("Latitude: " + data.lat + "<br />Longitude: " + data.lng);
                    }
                });
            }

        });
</script>
```

filterstores.php

```
$currloc = json_decode($_POST['latlng'], true);

$stores = array('lat'=>$currloc['lat'],'lng'=>$currloc['lng']);

echo json_encode($stores);
```

The following will be results what i got in returns once i hit the "share location" button pop up from the browser

```
Latitude: sdf
Longitude: sdfsd
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What is returning null for instance. You are showing a piece of Jquery. Is anything even executed? Check some sort of developer tools (f12 in chrome for instance) to see you request, do some `console.log` things to see if your code is actually run. Then add that debugging info here= (in the question, not in a comment!)

Comment: log php-script execution. See what you have in `$_POST['currloc']` and `$currloc` after `json_decode`.

Comment: AFAIK, if you use `datatype: "json"`, JQuery will automatically JSON encode the `data` you give. No need to do it on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making double json coding in your AJAX function. If something went wrong when codifying, JSON function will give you a null as an answer. You only have to pass the string without json codification and surely it'll work:

```
function showPosition(position) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "libs/filterstores.php",
    data: { lat:position.coords.latitude, lng:position.coords.longitude },        
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
    $('#geoloc').html("Latitude: " + data.lat + "<br />Longitude: " + data.lng);
    }
});
}
```

Your PHP only will have to accept the POST, without json encoding:

**PHP File:**

```
$lat = $_POST['lat'];
$lng = $_POST['lng'];

$stores = array('lat'=>$lat,'lng'=>$lng);

echo json_encode($stores);
```

Comment: Hi there, Thank you so much for the answer! That resolve the problems! I thought it has to specify clearly the JSON when passing to PHP so i include the contentType and the data in such format. Also i was hoping to learn to pass as an JSON array and that's why i code it the way i posted earlier. But in this case it'll be perfectly fine! I'll try look around see if i could find some advice on how to passing JSON array to PHP down the track. Thanks again Choco! Thanks a million!

Comment: @Wei Check my solution if you want to pass data as JSON array :)

Answer (score 2):

Should this line:

```
    data: { json: JSON.stringify(latlng) },
```

not specify *currloc* as the parameter?

i.e.

```
    data: { currloc: JSON.stringify(latlng) },
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for your feedback. i've tried that but it still showing NULL as mentioned above.

Comment: @Wei did you try console.log(data) within the success ? is there a response returned? Secondly try adding something similar to this:           error: function(xhr, ts, et){
              $('#geoloc').html(ts+' '+et);
          }

Comment: @Manju - Hello Manju, it returns Null for both lat and lng as i mentioned earlier. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just try to search 'sdfsd' or "sdfsd" and 'sdf' or "sdf"

And  you will yourself get solution to your problem.

Comment: is that assuming request to libs/filterstores.php was successful? Issues seems to be with the way request is sent.

Comment: i've tried changing the $stores = array('lat'=>$currloc['lat'],'lng'=>$currloc['lng']); to $stores = array('lat'=>'test lat','lng'=>'test lng'); and it does return as intended. It has to be somewhere between passing in from the client-side to server-side

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can **send and receive JSON data**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "filterstores.php",
        data: {json: latlng},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            $('#geoloc').html("Latitude: " + data.lat + "<br />Longitude: " + data.lng);
        }
});
```

And the PHP file

```
$currloc = $_GET['json'];
$stores = array('lat'=>$currloc[0]['lat'],'lng'=>$currloc[0]['lng']);
echo json_encode($stores);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$currloc = json_decode($_POST['json'], true);
```

instead

```
$currloc = json_decode($_POST['latlng'], true);
```

or try this in SCRIPT

```
     function showPosition(position) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "libs/filterstores.php",
                data: {"lat":position.coords.latitude, "lng":position.coords.longitude},
               dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){
                    $('#geoloc').html("Latitude: " + data.lat + "<br />Longitude: " + data.lng);
                }
            });
        }
```

IN PHP FILE

```
$stores = array('lat'=>$_POST['lat'],'lng'=>$_POST['lng']);

echo json_encode($stores);
```

Hope it will help

Comment: Did tried that before and just tried again. Doesn't work. Thank you